# Where does Struts a controller redirect when a form validation fails?

Tags: java, forms, jsp, struts

Does it redirect to the value in `input` attribute in the `action` element of `struts-config` file? How can we set the flag `redirect="true"` for the forward when validation fails? ( So that the url of page being redirected to, is shown in the browser instead of html:form action url. )

Comment: I haven't done Struts, but in most MVC frameworks I've worked with, a redirect will cause (request scoped) validation messages to get lost. I hope you've kept this in mind as well.

Comment: Yes I know. Thanks! And I have catered for that by saving validation messages in session, and then removing them from session once they are displayed.

Comment: Seems like there are not much Struts people in stackoverflow! :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are any validation errors, the "execute" method of the action class will not get called; instead the control will go back to the “input” file until the form has no ActionErrors associated with it. So your statement is correct, you get redirected to the value in the “input” attribute in the “action” element of “struts-config.xml”, or more exactly, you are forwarded there.

At this point you could forward to a JSP containing something like this in it:

```
<%response.sendRedirect(strWhereTo);%>
```

Or you could specify an action (*.do or what extension you are using) for the "input" attribute, where this action could be an instance of `org.apache.struts.action.RedirectingActionForward` which redirects to your JSP (it’s been a while since I used Struts, so I’m not so sure about this second method :D).

Hope this helps. Cheers!